# Caddy - How to disable https only for one domain

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

I have a config file for Caddy v2 like in below:

```
sentry.mydomain.ru {
    reverse_proxy sentry:9000
}

tasks.mydomain.ru {
    reverse_proxy taiga-proxy:80
}

ain.mydomain.ru {
    reverse_proxy ain-frontend:80
}
```

Caddy makes https for every domain but I need to make disable "https" only for `ain.mydomain.ru`.
How to do it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Caddy serves http traffic only if you prefix the domain with `http` scheme.

Here is the modified `Caddyfile`:

```
sentry.mydomain.ru {
    reverse_proxy sentry:9000
}

tasks.mydomain.ru {
    reverse_proxy taiga-proxy:80
}

http://ain.mydomain.ru {
    reverse_proxy ain-frontend:80
}
```

Reference: https://caddy.community/t/is-there-any-way-to-disable-tls-from-the-caddyfile/8372/2

Answer (score 5):

`domain:80` or `ip:80` will help you access your site on http mode. The example below ain.mydomain.ru will be available only on `http`. Also ensure `tls` directive is disabled for the domains you want to access via port 80 using `http` protocol only.

```
sentry.mydomain.ru {
reverse_proxy sentry:9000
}

tasks.mydomain.ru {
    reverse_proxy taiga-proxy:80
}

ain.mydomain.ru:80 {
    reverse_proxy ain-frontend:80
}
```